# ¿Como llenar un Html.DropdownListFor()?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Necesito llenar un `Html.DropdownListFor()` en mi vista por medio de razor, hasta ahora tengo lo siguiente, dos clases donde obtengo la data que necesito recuperar de mi db más el controlador por `GET` para recuperar la data y enviarla a la vista mediante un `ViewBag`

Hasta ahora tengo el siguiente código

**CLASES**

```
public class Region
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string NombreRegion { get; set; }

    public List<Region> Regiones { get; set; }
}


public class Data
{
    private Region _Region;

    public Data()
    {
        _Region = new Region();
    }

    public List<Region> GetRegion()
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DetamaticAPI.DataBase.Connection.ConnString))
            {
                string SQL = string.Empty;

                SQL += "SELECT id, Region";
                SQL += " FROM Region";

                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQL, conn);
                    SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                    DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
                    sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataset, "Region");
                    conn.Close();

                    for (int i = 0; i < dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                    _    Region.Regiones.Add(new Region()
                        {
                            Id= Convert.ToInt32(dataset.Tables[0].Rows[i]["id"].ToString()),
                            NombreRegion= dataset.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Region"].ToString()
                        });
                    }

                    return _Region.Regiones;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

**CONTROLADOR** POR GET

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Region = _Data.GetRegion();
    return View();
}
```

**VISTA**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Region, new SelectList(ViewBag.Region, "Value", "Text"))
```

Pero todo lo anterior me devuelve la siguiente excepcion

> System.Web.HttpException: 'DataBinding: 'DetamaticTotem.Controllers.Region' no contiene una propiedad con el nombre 'Value'.'

Bueno como dice ahi es por que no contiene la spropiedades `value` y `text`... como deberia crear esta lista para que contenga esas propiedades? Habia visto el `SelectList` y `SelectListItem` pero no se como usarlas o modificar mi cpodigo para implementarlo..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes trabajarlo con `SelectList` o `SelectListItem`

En caso de ser `SelectList`

Deberías usar la sobrecarga siguiente

```
new SelectList(
   Tu Lista,
   Value de tu lista,
   Texto de tu lista,
   Valor seleccionado de tu lista
   )
```

Tendrías que usarlo de la siguiente manera

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Region, new SelectList(ViewBag.Region,"Id","NombreRegion",Model.Region))
```

y en caso de ser `SelectListItem` tendrías que modificar un poco tu controlador

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Region = _Data.GetRegion().Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
                Text = x.NombreRegion,
                Value = x.Id.ToString()
        });
    return View();
}
```

Luego en la vista, lo usarías de la siguiente manera

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Region, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Region)
```

Saludos

Comment: Gracias, me fue util