# Problemas en mostrar datos en combo box en pantalla con petición Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, c#

He realizado un servicio rest realizado con C# con petición ajax con combo box, pero este a su vez no muestra datos, la cual tengo un objeto html 5 como objeto combo box la cual debe llenar datos de una ciudad, pero esta no muestra las ciudades que realice en el servicio rest, esa muestra como no definido en el objeto del combo box, la sintaxis **undefined**, anexo código fuente

```
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">

                <label>Ciudad</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="Ciudad" name="Ciudad" onchange="ValidarExisteCiudad()">
                    <option>Seleccione ...</option>
                    <option> </option>
                </select>

            </div>
```

```
function ValidarExisteCiudad() {
    var existeUsuario;   


        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "CargaCiudad",
            async: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {


                $.each(data, function (key, registro) {
                    $("#Ciudad").append('<option value=' + registro.IdCiudad + '>' + registro.Nombre + '</option>');
                });
            },  
            error: function (data) {
                alertify('Error.' + data.error.message);
                existeUsuario = false;
            }
        });

    return existeUsuario;

}
```

```
 [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CargaCiudad()
        {
            List<Cuidad> Items = await drHelpPrueba.Cuidad.ToListAsync();
            int Count = Items.Count();
            return Json(new { Items, Count });
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que un [dropdownlistfor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/193592/como-llenar-un-html-dropdownlistfor) te puede ayudar a simplificar tus select si usas mvc

Comment: te da undefined porque no existe el atributo IdCiudad  puedes agregar tu JSON?

Comment: @NicolasOñate en .Net Core el uso de html helpers ya no es recomendado (aunque todavía se puede usar). Ahora es con un select/option con su propiedad asp-items="tu_select_list".

Answer (score 2):

Tu ciclo each está buscando en data directamente, cuando tu lista está en los items de data (data.items). Por lo que con este cambio debería de funcionar:

```
$.each(data.items, function (index, value) {
     $("#Ciudad").append('<option value=' + value.idCiudad + '>' + value.nombre + '</option>');
});
```

*nota: fíjate en el cambio en el nombre de la propiedad de nombre también. Tú lo tenías con mayúscula inicial y debe de ser con minúscula.

Answer (score 0):

También puede solucionar mediante el siguiente código

```
 [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CargaCiudad()
        {
            List<Cuidad> Items = await drHelpPrueba.Cuidad.ToListAsync();
            List<SelectListItem> ciudad = new List<SelectListItem>();

            for (int i = 0; i < Items.Count; i++)
            {
                ciudad.Add(new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = Convert.ToString(Items.ToList()[i].IdCiudad),
                    Text = Items.ToList()[i].Nombre
                });
            }

            return Json(ciudad);

        }
```

JavaScript

```
function ValidarExisteCiudad() {
    var existeUsuario;   

    var ddlCiudad = $("#Ciudad");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "CargaCiudad",
            data: '{}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {

                existeUsuario = true;
                ddlCiudad.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Seleccione ...</option>');
                $.each(data, function () {
                   ddlCiudad.append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
                });
            },  
            failure: function (data) {
                alert(data.responseText);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert(data.responseText);
                existeUsuario = false;
            }
        });

    return existeUsuario;

}
```