# ¿Como agrego un combobox de 1 de los campos de mi BD sin que las opciones provengan de una BD estoy con MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Estoy trabajando con Entity Framework en MVC,
Tengo 1 tabla llamada MovimientoCaja con campos(Fecha,Grupo,Entrada,Salida etc)
Lo que quiero implementar es en la parte del campo "Grupo"  despliegue un par de opciones y  la que elija el usuario la inserte a la a la BD en el campo "Grupo", Hice una pequeña practica de como extraer las opciones de la BD pero   no  se  como estas opciones se las asigno a mi  campo "Grupo" e insertar a la BD
Estas Opciones pueden estar en la BD o con el controlador ya que son 2 o 5 opciones fijas
Estoy usando un controlador  Entity con vistas de Crear, Modificar, Eliminar
Aqui obtengo las opciones y las muestro en la vista[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

```
namespace PruebaFinanzas2.Models.ViewModel
```

{
public class ClaseViewTiposCaja
{
public int _IdTipoCaja { get; set; }
public string _TipoCaja { get; set; }
}
}

---

Controlador

```
  public ActionResult Create()
    {
        List<Models.ViewModel.ClaseViewTiposCaja> lst = null;
        lst = (from d in db.TipoDeCaja
               select new Models.ViewModel.ClaseViewTiposCaja
               {
                   _IdTipoCaja = d.IdTipoCaja,
                   _TipoCaja = d.TipoCaja
               }
         ).ToList();
        List<SelectListItem> items = lst.ConvertAll(d =>
        {
            return new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = d._TipoCaja.ToString(),
                Value = d._IdTipoCaja.ToString(),
                Selected = false
            };
        }
        );
        ViewBag.items = items;
        return View();
    }
```

---

Vista

```
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TipoCaja, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">

        @Html.DropDownList("items", items, "Selecciona", new { @class = "form-controil" })

        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TipoCaja, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TipoCaja, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>`
```

Comment: Por favor, copia y pega el código como texto

Comment: Listo Amigo Ya lo pase a Texto

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como llenar un Html.DropdownListFor()?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/193592/como-llenar-un-html-dropdownlistfor)